# Batch updates: StatementType enumeration value, 4 is invalid / Invalid operation. The connection is closed

Tags: .net, enterprise-library, batch-updates

I am using Enterprise Library's Data Access Block.

My code is doing large batch updates, but for one of our customers it always ends up failing with one of the following exceptions:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: The StatementType enumeration value, 4, is invalid.
Parameter name: StatementType
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.UpdatedRowStatusErrors(RowUpdatedEventArgs rowUpdatedEvent, BatchCommandInfo[] batchCommands, Int32 commandCount)
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.UpdatedRowStatus(RowUpdatedEventArgs rowUpdatedEvent, BatchCommandInfo[] batchCommands, Int32 commandCount)
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Update(DataRow[] dataRows, DataTableMapping tableMapping)
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.UpdateFromDataTable(DataTable dataTable, DataTableMapping tableMapping)
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Update(DataSet dataSet, String srcTable)
```

and

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid operation. The connection is closed. at
System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.UpdatedRowStatusErrors(RowUpdatedEventArgs rowUpdatedEvent, BatchCommandInfo[] batchCommands, Int32 commandCount) at
System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.UpdatedRowStatus(RowUpdatedEventArgs rowUpdatedEvent, BatchCommandInfo[] batchCommands, Int32 commandCount) at
System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Update(DataRow[] dataRows, DataTableMapping tableMapping) at
System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.UpdateFromDataTable(DataTable dataTable, DataTableMapping tableMapping) at
System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Update(DataTable dataTable) at
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database.DoUpdateDataSet(UpdateBehavior behavior, DataSet dataSet, String tableName, IDbCommand insertCommand, IDbCommand updateCommand, IDbCommand deleteCommand, Nullable`1 updateBatchSize) at
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database.UpdateDataSet(DataSet dataSet, String tableName, DbCommand insertCommand, DbCommand updateCommand, DbCommand deleteCommand, UpdateBehavior updateBehavior, Nullable`1 updateBatchSize) at
```

Answer (score 2):

I have searched the internet for a while, without being able to find what these errors mean or how to fix them. Now that I have finally found the answer, I am sharing it.

The errors always occurred after 10 minutes. It was actually a **timeout**.

Raising the value of my `transactionScope.TransactionOptions.Timeout` didn't help; checking if MSDTC was correctly configured didn't help either.

I got it to work by inserting the following:

```
<system.transactions>
    <machineSettings maxTimeout="20:00:00"/>
</system.transactions>
```

into the **machine.config** files that can be found here:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config
```

Hope this helps someone, someday...